# Error Android Studio Attempt to invoke virtual method in reading data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm following a youtube tutorial to read realtime database from firebase. The child value is send with intent from login page to main page. There's no error in code instead I got the error like below when attempting to open the main page.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project/com.example.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference

for the code is below

```
 Button tambah, panggil, admin;
DatabaseReference reff;
public static final String TAG = "gakpenting";
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private List<sensor> sensors = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getExtras().getString("kode");
    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(value);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleview_sensor);
    new MainActivity().readsensor(new datastatus() {
        @Override
        public void DataIsLoaded(List<sensor> sensors, List<String> keys) {
            new RecyclerView_Config().setConfig(mRecyclerView, MainActivity.this, sensors, keys);
        }

        @Override
        public void DataIsInserted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void DataIsUpdated() {

        }

        @Override
        public void DataIsDeleted() {

        }
    });


    tambah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tambah);
    tambah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openaddmember();
        }
    });

    admin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.admin);
    admin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openadmin();
        }
    });

    panggil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.panggil);
    panggil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("damkar");
            reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                    // whenever data at this location is updated.
                    String damkar = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + damkar));

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    startActivity(callintent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

public void openaddmember() {
    Intent child = getIntent();
    String value = child.getExtras().getString("kode");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, statalat.class);
    intent.putExtra("kode", value);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openadmin() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, statalat.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public interface datastatus {
    void DataIsLoaded(List<sensor> sensors, List<String> keys);

    void DataIsInserted();

    void DataIsUpdated();

    void DataIsDeleted();
}

public void readsensor(final datastatus Datastatus) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String value = intent.getExtras().getString("kode");
    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(value);
    reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            sensors.clear();
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot keynode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                keys.add(keynode.getKey());
                sensor Sensor = keynode.getValue(sensor.class);
                sensors.add(Sensor);
            }
            Datastatus.DataIsLoaded(sensors, keys);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This code is used to make reading and a few buttons below the textview. Please help.

Comment: At which particular line of code does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of "FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(....)" is returning NULL. It seems the one in "readsensor()" method. Please check if the "value" is filled with the right String before use it!